# asp.net (VB) <> is not a parameter for stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following ASP.NET (VB) code below.
My goal is to get the output of a stored proc that accepts 1 parameter and store that info
into a data table:

```
        Dim strConnection1 As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Rdf2012")
        Dim conn1 As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        conn1 = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(strConnection1)
        Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand
        Dim prm1 As New SqlParameter
        Dim dtDataTable1 As DataTable
        cmd1.Connection = conn1
        cmd1.CommandText = "usp_GetDetails"
        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        prm1 = cmd1.Parameters.Add(strProgramID, SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)
        prm1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input

        conn1.Open()

        Dim dataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd1

        Dim ds1 As New DataSet
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds1)
        conn1.Close()

        dtDataTable1 = ds1.Tables("Table1")
```

Program stops at

```
    dataAdapter.Fill(ds1) and says:
```

@1012952-4403 is not a parameter for procedure usp_GetDetails

This is what the stored proc looks like:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetDetails]
@ProId VARCHAR(20) = NULL
    AS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do

```
prm1 = cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@ProID", strProgramID)
```

instead of

```
 prm1 = cmd1.Parameters.Add(strProgramID, SqlDbType.VarChar, 50) 
 prm1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
```

Direction will be assumed to be input unless otherwise specified.

Comment: As I need to store this merely into a datatable, is the dataadapter part necessary?

Comment: The dataadapter is, but you don't need a dataset. You can fill directly to a datatable. ie dataAdapter.Fill(dtDataTable1 )

Answer (score 1):

Verify what strProgramID is equal to. You might be passing parameter value where parameter name is expected. If that's the case, replace

```
Dim prm1 As New SqlParameter
....
prm1 = cmd1.Parameters.Add(strProgramID, SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)
prm1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
```

with

```
 cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProId",strProgramID)
```

Comment: As I need to store this merely into a datatable, is the dataadapter part necessary?

Comment: Using DataAdapter's Fill method is one way to get data into DataTable. Another way is to use DataTable's Load method - to which you can pass a DataReader, in this case DataAdapter is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating parameter in a wrong way, try this:

```
Dim strConnection1 As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Rdf2012")
    Dim conn1 As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    conn1 = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(strConnection1)
    Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand
    Dim dtDataTable1 As DataTable
    cmd1.Connection = conn1
    cmd1.CommandText = "usp_GetDetails"
    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@ProId",strProgramID)

    conn1.Open()

    Dim dataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter
    dataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd1

    Dim ds1 As New DataSet
    dataAdapter.Fill(ds1)
    conn1.Close()

    dtDataTable1 = ds1.Tables("Table1")
```